# Returning value from a recursive function involving Promise

Tags: protractor

I am trying to return value from a recursive function involving Promises.
Here's the example method:

```
getRecursionValue = function(count, i, num, isFound) {

    if (i < count && !isFound) {
        somePage.someNum.then(function(numVal) {
            if (numVal == num) {
                console.log('Matched at index: ' + i);
                <RETURN VALUE OF I>
            } else {
                element(by.css('css.for.next.link')).click();
                utils.getRecursionValue(count, i + 1, num, false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am not able to return the value of 'i' correctly! Any suggestions for a  way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sakshi

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from inside a promise but the promise in turn returns nothing to the function. You can solve this by returning the first promise which will in turn return the value of i:

```
getRecursionValue = function(count, i, num, isFound) {

if (i < count && !isFound) {
    return somePage.someNum.then(function(numVal) {
        if (numVal == num) {
            console.log('Matched at index: ' + i);
            <RETURN VALUE OF I>
        }
```

Comment: I think the `utils.getRecurisonValue` line also needs to be prefixed with `return`, too.

Comment: Thanks P.T. That actually resolved the issue. But I dnt really understand how it worked!